# JFace CTabFolder, toggle between tabs

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

I'm working on an app in JFace. So I have a CTabFolder with a number of CTabItems in it. What I would like is to be able to automatically switch to display an arbitrary CTabItem.

What I'm thinking is something like:

```
CTabFolder myFolder = FolderFactory.newFolder();
myFolder.showItem(myFolder.getItem((ARBITRARY_INT)));

    /*These don't help!*/
    //myFolder.update();
    //myFolder.pack();
    //myFolder.redraw();
```

The folder works just fine by itself. i.e. users may tab through with the mouse. The difference is that I would like to be able to show different tabs by default in different perspectives.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `CTabFolder#setSelection(..)`. The show item only shows the item, like if there are a lot of items and some are hidden, this method will scroll to them.